# Whatsapp chat history Transfer to android phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluetooth, data-recovery, file-transfer, redmi-1s

Presently, I am using WhatsApp on my Nokia Xpressmisic 5530. Earlier, I had used it in Xiaomi. I need to transfer chats from Nokia to my android phone.

Inside Nokia, it only have two options:

1. Via Bluetooth
2. Upload.

My upload function failed. Then, next option is to send through Bluetooth. How can it be send and load inside android device? Is this possible?

Comment: Rahul, What is the file format of the Whatsapp backup file in your Nokia mobile. ?

Comment: Its a text file with extension .txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't restore chat history from one platform to a different platform.

Eg:- Window to Android or vice-versa as in your case. Read the below Whatsapp faq,

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/28060005

It tells,

> You cannot restore chat history from any other phone type to Windows
>   Phone, or from Windows Phone to another phone type.

The Whatsapp for Symbian S60 OS creates backup file as `.bak` files and Whatsapp on Android OS  creates backup files as `.crypt` files(encrypted). So based on this article from Whatsapp on [How to save and restore chat history backups](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/s60/23245511). The instructions are given only for

- transferring backups from S60 to S60 phone
- Backup files are saved in a folder called ‘wa’ and are called MsgStore.bak which will not be recognized by the Whatsapp application in your Android phone.
- Backup files are saved in a format to be opened with WhatsApp. If you want to read your conversations on your computer you can send them as .txt file from WhatsApp to your email.

What you are trying to do is export the chat history. And from this Whatsapp article on [How do I export my chat history?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/s60/21055276),

You can't use this `.txt` file for importing into another phone. So What you do is only for exporting the chat and you can only be able to read it using a text editor.

> it is not possible to restore your chat history from this exported
>   .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use in copying it: I think it won't work, Nokia xpressmusic is a Symbian  phone and XiaoMi is not Symbian.

The WhatsApp database will be different for both the phones. So, they may not be compatible.